# How to get the mplayer's single-line playing progress info?

Tags: shell

mplayer shows and **refreshes** a single-line playing progress when playing a media file. A sample result is:

```
A:  17.2 (17.2) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.5%
```

And I'm trying to grep this playing progress and ignore other lines. I used this command:

```
mplayer xxx.mp3 | grep ^A:
```

The result does not contain the line expected.

```
mplayer xxx.mp3 | od -xda
```

shows:

```
0002140    4a5b    410d    203a    2020    2e31    2033    3028    2e31
          [   J  \r   A   :               1   .   3       (   0   1   .
        133 112 015 101 072 040 040 040 061 056 063 040 050 060 061 056
0002160    2932    6f20    2066    3132    2e33    2030    3028    3a33
          2   )       o   f       2   1   3   .   0       (   0   3   :
        062 051 040 157 146 040 062 061 063 056 060 040 050 060 063 072
0002200    3333    302e    2029    3020    342e    2025    5b1b    0d4a
          3   3   .   0   )           0   .   4   %     033   [   J  \r
        063 063 056 060 051 040 040 060 056 064 045 040 033 133 112 015
0002220    3a41    2020    3120    352e    2820    3130    342e    2029
          A   :               1   .   5       (   0   1   .   4   )    
        101 072 040 040 040 061 056 065 040 050 060 061 056 064 051 040
0002240    666f    3220    3331    302e    2820    3330    333a    2e33
          o   f       2   1   3   .   0       (   0   3   :   3   3   .
        157 146 040 062 061 063 056 060 040 050 060 063 072 063 063 056
```

And

```
mplayer xxx.mp3 | tr '\r' '\n'
```

shows

```
A:   0.2 (00.1) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.3% 
A:   0.3 (00.3) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.3% 
A:   0.5 (00.5) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.4% 
A:   0.6 (00.6) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.4% 
A:   0.8 (00.8) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.4% 
A:   1.0 (01.0) of 213.0 (03:33.0)  0.4%
```

While,

```
mplayer xxx.mp3 | tr '\r' '\n' | grep ^A
```

shows empty result.

---

update:

```
mplayer sample.mp3| sed -une 's/^A://p' 2>&1
```

shows:

```
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
Requested audio codec family [mpg123] (afm=mpg123) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
```

My PC environment:

OS: Ubuntu 12.04, shell: dash

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking. Does the updated answer help?

Comment: @Morpfh: No. It seems that the refreshing line can not be captured by tools like sed and grep.